# Sending GPS values via XBee and Arduino (Float problem!!!)

Tags: arduino, gps, xbee

I have XBEE S2C's. I have 2 Arduino MEGA.  One part of them will be receiver and other is transmitter. I communicated and configured XBee's.I tested it That's okey. But the problem is I can't send float value like   longtitude= 38,45682469  latitude= 85,24698534. When I try to do this I receive only latitude = 85
longtitude = 38.   How can I change my code to receive healthy data.

TRANSMITTER

```
    #include "SoftwareSerial.h"

#include <TinyGPS.h>

float lat,lon;

TinyGPS gps; 

SoftwareSerial XBee(10, 11);

void setup(){

Serial.begin(9600);

  XBee.begin(9600);

Serial.println("The GPS Received Signal:");

Serial3.begin(9600);

}
 
void loop(){

    while(Serial3.available()){ 

    if(gps.encode(Serial3.read()))

    {

    gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lon); 

    Serial.print("Position: ");

    Serial.print("Latitude: ");

    Serial.print(lat,8);

    Serial.print(",");

    Serial.print("Longitude: ");


    Serial.println(lon,8);

    }
  }
  
XBee.write("l");
  
XBee.write(lat);

delay(100);   
         
XBee.write("k");

XBee.write(lon);

delay(100);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending 3 float variables with serial software on Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844625/sending-3-float-variables-with-serial-software-on-arduino)

Comment: You can have a few decimal digits with a float in the range +-180.xxx. But not as many as you want and get via GPS. Perhaps you have a look at https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus , which uses a special data type for lat and lon

Comment: Currently, you only transmit a single byte via XBee.
Change `XBee.write(lat);` to `XBee.print(lat);` On the receiver side you need to parse the incoming text.

Answer (score 0):

Most robust is to convert float to string, send it over serial, and let the receiver convert back to float.

Sender:

```
XBee.write(String(lat,5)); // keep 5 decimals
```

Receiver:

```
String inString = "";
while (Serial.available()) {
  char c = Serial.read(); 
  inString += c; 
}
float myFloat = inString.toFloat();
```

Further reading:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToFloatExample
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.StringConstructor